# no such tool "asm"

Tags: go

I am trying to install golang and run it with visual code. I have followed all the steps to install it, however whenever I run it on my visual code and try to install the recommended features I get the following errors:

```
Installing github.com/mdempsky/gocode FAILED Installing github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/cmd/gopkgs FAILED Installing github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline FAILED Installing github.com/acroca/go-symbols FAILED Installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru FAILED Installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename FAILED Installing github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv FAILED Installing github.com/stamblerre/gocode FAILED Installing github.com/rogpeppe/godef FAILED Installing github.com/ianthehat/godef FAILED Installing github.com/sqs/goreturns FAILED Installing github.com/golang/lint/golint FAILED

12 tools failed to install.

gocode: Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v github.com/mdempsky/gocode github.com/mdempsky/gocode (download) go tool: no such tool "asm" github.com/mdempsky/gocode (download) go tool: no such tool "asm"

gopkgs: Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v github.com/uudashr/gopkgs/cmd/gopkgs github.com/uudashr/gopkgs (download) github.com/karrick/godirwalk (download) github.com/pkg/errors (download) go tool: no such tool "asm" github.com/uudashr/gopkgs (download) github.com/karrick/godirwalk (download) github.com/pkg/errors (download) go tool: no such tool "asm"

go-outline: Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline (download) Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 (status code 200) get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": verifying non-authoritative meta tag Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200) golang.org/x/tools (download) go tool: no such tool "asm" github.com/ramya-rao-a/go-outline (download) Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 (status code 200) get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": verifying non-authoritative meta tag Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200) golang.org/x/tools (download) go tool: no such tool "asm"

go-symbols: Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v github.com/acroca/go-symbols github.com/acroca/go-symbols (download) Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 (status code 200) get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": verifying non-authoritative meta tag Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200) golang.org/x/tools (download) go tool: no such tool "asm" github.com/acroca/go-symbols (download) Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 (status code 200) get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": found meta tag get.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": verifying non-authoritative meta tag Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200) golang.org/x/tools (download) go tool: no such tool "asm"
```

Here's my go env

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>go env
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\Publio\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\gocode
set GOPROXY=
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\Publio\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build872751422=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Comment: How did you install Go? Try to set the environment variable "GOBIN=" to its real path.

Comment: to be precise, i followed this exact tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f1rZ47Gj7x4. And thanks for answering, how do i set that path?

Answer (score 2):

I did found the same error.
[image: no asm]

turn out that my antivirus blocked the asm.exe files. so I have to **exclude the go directory from anti-virus scanning**. after that **re-install go or just repair installation** do the work too.

[image]

Comment: please use text instead of pictures.

Comment: Helped me too...plus one!